# ASP.NET Core Web API : session cookie removed after page refresh

Tags: c#, authentication, session, cookies, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm new to sessions/cookies for auth so I'm getting to know about everything slowly.

I have a Web API that has some endpoints to login and also a protected endpoint that can only be accessed once the cookie is issued and not expired.

Just for testing purposes of how it would be handled in the frontend, I created a simple form which calls these endpoints.

The login endpoint works and I do get a cookie that I configured in my backend, but for the other protected endpoint I get a **302 Found** error (I have a button that calls this protected endpoint after I'm logged in), even though this works when I use postman. ie, I can access the protected endpoint. This redirects me to a different endpoint which I don't have set up (I'm guessing its a endpoint set by .NET?)

Login endpoint:

[image]

Authorized endpoint when calling it directly after login:

[image: auth]

Another thing is that this cookie that the backend issues gets deleted after my page is reloaded/refreshed and I don't know why.

I would also appreciate any guidance on how to effectively handle session authentication on both front and backend securely.

Here's my code:

Authentication config - I set it to a low expiration time for testing

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationCookieAuth(this IServiceCollection services) 
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options => {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddCookie(options => {
            options.Cookie = new() {
                Name = "MySessionAuthCookie",
                HttpOnly = true
            };
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });

    return services;
}
```

Controller endpoints:

```
// Protected endpoint
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult GetProtectedData() 
{
    return Ok("Protected data");
}

[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginRequest request) 
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.Email);

    if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, request.Password))
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")
        };

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        
        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true };

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);

        return Ok("Login success");
    }

    return Unauthorized();
}
```

My frontend is just regular HTML and JS for demo purposes.

```js
async function protectedEndpoint() {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get("https://localhost:7009/api/auth", {withCredentials: true, });
        console.log('Response:', res);

    } catch(err) {
        console.error('Error:', err);
    }
}

async function authenticate(data) {
    try {
        const res = await axios.post("https://localhost:7009/api/auth/login", data, {withCredentials: true});
        console.log('Response:', res);
    } catch(err) {
        console.error('Error:', err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try creating a project with an MVC template and using the same code to see if you can reproduce the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the CookiePolicyOptions with something like this

```
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ConsentCookie.IsEssential = true;
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
```

and read the microsoft learn page specially the Security and Identity section, here you can learn multiple auth types [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-8.0)